# Execute function only if window width is greater than something else don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

```
 function dropdownHover() {
   jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
 }, function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
 });
}


$(window).on('resize', function(event){
   var windowSize = $(window).width(); 
   if(windowSize > 992){
      dropdownHover();
   } 
});
```

I need this function dropdownHover() to fire only when window is greater than 992px, both on load and on resize, else if window is < 992px, both on load or on resize i dont want to fire this function on hover i want regular bootstrap dropdown on click. I tried to do this with css but i cant add animation on dropdown because its just display: none/block. I also tried to add class on resize to fire this function if element has that class else dont but it doesnt work either.

Edit: Final working version

```
$('.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function(){
  if(!$(this).is('.open') && $(window).data('wide'))
     $('.dropdown-menu', this).dropdown('toggle').hide()
        .stop(true, true)
        .delay(200)
        .fadeIn(function(){
            this.style.display = '';
        }).find('a').on('touchstart click', function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation(); 
      });
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
if($(this).is('.open') && $(window).data('wide'))
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).dropdown('toggle');
});

$('.dropdown').on('click', function(e){
  if( $(window).data('wide')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).dropdown('toggle');
} else {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this)
        .stop(true, true).slideToggle()
        .closest('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  }
});

// not entirely necessary.  Not sure which is faster: this or just checking the width in all three places.
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  $(window).data('wide', $(window).width() > 992);

// reset the open menues
$('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
$('.dropdown-menu').css({
    display: '',
    left: '',
    position: '',
 });

// because we are checking the width of the window, this should probably go here although this really should be a media query style
$('.dropdown-menu.pull-center').each(function() {
    var menuW = $(this).outerWidth();
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        $(this).css({
            left: - menuW / 2 + 60 + 'px',
            position: 'absolute'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            left: '',
            position: ''
        });
    }
 });
 }).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Initial Solution

Your question is twofold.  First, you need it to not show the menu at smaller sizes.  For that, you check on resize what the window width is.  The problem is that it only works once.  It triggers the event listeners for `hover` and it doesn't kill those event listeners if the screen is then larger at some point.  For that, you can set a flag.  There are a lot of ways to do this, but for my answer, I've chosen to use jQuery `.data()` method.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var windowSizeWide = $(window).width() > 600; // reduced for testing purposes
    jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').data('dropdown-enabled', windowSizeWide);
}).trigger('resize');
```

Then when we listen for the hover events (which are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events), we simply return out of the function if the screen is too small.

```
jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if(!jQuery(this).data('dropdown-enabled')) return;
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    if(!jQuery(this).data('dropdown-enabled')) return;
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
}).find('.dropdown-menu').hide();
```

Finally, you also want the event to trigger on load.  You can do that by simply adding `.trigger('resize')` as seen in the first snippet.  You can see a functioning demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/xw9Ljshu/

### Possible Alternative Solution

Alternatively, you can also use CSS to handle this with media queries.  The simplest way to do this is to force `display: none` on smaller screens.  I don't recommend completely hiding the element because it becomes inaccessible at that point, but this is the general idea:

```
@media(max-width: 600px) {
    ul.dropdown-menu {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Note that `!important` is used because jQuery adds inline styles when you `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`.

Second demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/xw9Ljshu/1

Comment: Wow thanks this works great but just one thing. Instead of hover function which is killed on small window i need regular bootstrap dropdown function which doesn't work now. Or maybe i could add other slideToggle function on CLICK. Important thing is it must be on click. Just to note dropdown is in main navigation bar which is triggered on toggle button.

Comment: @NenadVracar ok.  That makes more sense.  So really you want a dropdown to open on hover for desktop views?

Comment: Yes, basically window > 992 open on hover, window < 992 open on click. 992 is bootstrap navbar breaking point so it just cant be on hover.

Comment: @NenadVracar I'm sorry I couldn't revisit this yesterday.  I got a bit too busy.  Is [this the kind of functionality you're after?](http://www.bootply.com/2q8akHaq3Y)  Dropdown is a little funky.  It doesn't allow you to explicitly hide or show.  You can only toggle.  This makes changing its functionality a bit hard.  In my demo that I linked I ended up having to stop the propagation at the anchor.  It'll let the anchor still work but doesn't allow click events higher up the tree.  Otherwise it was causing the menu to blink in and out.  May not solve your question, but yet another option.

Comment: First let me say thank you,  that code you gave me is awesome and it helped  me a lot. I edited my original question with new code (its your code with some modifications i added) and if its not too much to ask could you just take a look and say what you think. Also i cant open that link from comment above i get this msg (An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.)

Comment: Seems bootply is having problems again. :\  I've migrated the code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkm8xjyr/). changed it again... but the principle is the same.  I'll look over your code now too.

Comment: O yea that is perfect, only that last part of my code which puts dropdown-menu always in middle relatively to dropdown with pull-center class i am not sure where to put that. That needs to run only on > 992

Comment: Interesting.  The centering of that menu should probably be handled by a media query if possible.  In any case, here is an updated version of my code.  I looked into yours as well and it works with the one exception of the menu reverting to a dropdown style at smaller screens because of the transition.  Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/jkm8xjyr/3/  edit: updated it again... I have slight perfectionist tendencies. :P

Comment: I am developing a theme so i am not sure about width of dropdown-menu (i forgot to mention its multicolumn dropdown menu or mega-menu if you will :) ) so it must be flexible. Maybe i could do like this   left: -20vw or something but i think this is the best way. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, sounds right for this particular case.  It was just a suggestion anyway.  If you're making a theme, it makes sense that it would need to make the calculations.

Comment: And if its between slide animation on small screens and overall speed of code i choose speed. That slide animation is not necessary. And forgive me my noobishness at javascript :)

Comment: In that case, you could probably leave out the animations and leave the showing and hiding of the menu up to bootstrap.  Additionally, if users want to add animation to their menus with your theme, they can do it with CSS transitions or animations. Also, no need to apologize.  Stackoverflow is where I learned all that I know about javascript.  It's a fantastic place to learn it regardless of skill level.

Comment: With that last code you provided (i copy/pasted it) when i hover directly from one anchor to other or from one.dropdown-toggle to another on my site it blinks and doesnt show other dropdown-many just stays on same. But i can use that first part of previous code and last part of that last code and it works great.

Comment: Ok i just removed function(){
                this.style.display = '';
            } from fade functions and now everything  its working great.

Answer (score 0):

window.screen.availWidth to get the window size. i am yet not tested your code.But i think this will ok.

```
        function dropdownHover() {
        jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
        }, function() {
            jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
        });
    }     

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).on('resize', function(event){
            var windowSize = window.screen.availWidth; 
            if(windowSize > 992){
                dropdownHover();
            } 
        });

    })
```

Comment: This won't work.  OP already has this.  This will not kill the event handler if the window is resized to a smaller width.  It also doesn't trigger the resize event on load.  Therefore, it's very possible this code will never run.

Comment: @JosephMarikle  i tested with $(document).ready(function(){ ... }) and its working i think. would you try please ?

Comment: The code you provided functions but it doesn't do what the original poster specified.  It functions exactly like the code in the question.  You can replicate the problem by first loading the code while the screen is wider than 992px, resizing it down, and noticing that the hover menu appears.  It shouldn't appear at smaller screen sizes.  Note that the original poster wants it to check "both on **load** and on **resize**"

Comment: Its not working, i need this function to run document load if window is > 992 and when i resize window i need to kill it. Right now it doesn't work on document load, but when i resize window. Maybe if i create another function click-slide inside else{} do you think that will work.

Comment: I tested with a alert in function dropdownHover() .and the alert is coming when screen resize  with condition. :( just a second i am trying this  else part.

Comment: @Dking You can test with this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/umb3jz9y/.  If you start out with a large screen and then resize to a smaller one, the dropdown menu still appears.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yeah the menu list still appears .